# how to make Qrcode scanner in django

Tags: python, django, qr-code

how i can make qrcode scanner in django like  [this web](https://webqr.com/) so i can see the result in text not in image video

i already make the views.py like this

```
def camera_feed(request):
    stream = CameraStream()
    frames = stream.get_frames()
    return StreamingHttpResponse(frames, content_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


def detect(request):
    stream = CameraStream()
    success, frame = stream.camera.read()
    if success:
        status = True
    else:
        status = False
        
    return render(request, 'detect_barcodes/detect.html', context={'cam_status': status})
```

my camera_stream.py

```
class CameraStream(str):
    def __init__(self):
        self.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def get_frames(self):
        while True:
            # Capture frame-by-frame
            success, frame = self.camera.read()
            if not success:
                break
            else:
                ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
                color_image = np.asanyarray(frame)
                if decode(color_image):
                    for barcode in decode(color_image):
                        barcode_data = (barcode.data).decode('utf-8')                            
                else:
                    frame = buffer.tobytes()
                    #hasil2 = b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + barcode_frame + b'\r\n\r\n'                        
                    yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                           b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
```

this is my urls.py

```
path('camera_feed', views.camera_feed, name='camera_feed'),
path('detect_barcodes', views.detect, name='detect_barcodes'),
```

and i use the html like this

```
<img src="{% url 'qrcode' request.path %}" width="120px" height="120px;">
```

how i can pass the result in html?

Answer (score 0):

U should use js instascan rather using open cv2 no need to use backend because sever load increases and you easily pas decode value